# Need PHP Email Script Solution

Tags: php, email, server-side

Designing forms has always been fun, but getting them to send email on the server side is another story. I have used various email scripts (dynaform,phpmailer, etc), and have experienced a ton of problems.

So here is the site I am working on: [Contact On the Right](http://v2.ztmag.com/livedates.html). It is very basic: no validation, no required fields. I simply need anything that is entered to be sent back to me.

Does anyone know of any BASIC PHP form processing scripts, or have a few lines of code that would work here? I'm not a PHP guy, so I am struggling!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I simply need anything that is entered
>   to be sent back to me.

```
<?php
mail('your@mail.here','Site feedback',implode("\n\n",$_POST));
header("Location: thankyou.html");
?>
```

you can add this tag into thankyou.html:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="5;URL=http://v2.ztmag.com/livedates.html">
```

it will get user back in 5 seconds

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: POST in /home/jessechase/ztmag.com/v2/email.php  on line 2

Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/jessechase/ztmag.com/v2/email.php on line 2

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/jessechase/ztmag.com/v2/email.php:2) in /home/jessechase/ztmag.com/v2/email.php on line 3

Comment: I receive this error message. I do receive an email, but with nothing in it.

Comment: Actually this works out fine! Its exactly what I needed, although what is the PHP I need to write for the subject field in the email? I also want the email to be coming from the email address entered in the field

Comment: @JCHASE11 better don't do it, because it will bring your script into spam-gate. You have all info in the email body. that's enough

Comment: Fair enough. I guess It would be nice to have the subject line saying, "Live Date Submission" so I can easily recognize it in my email box, but if not, its no big deal.

Comment: @ JCHASE11 that's not a problem, this one. just change 'Site feedback' to 'Live Date Submission' in the code. You can write anything there save for the user entered data.

Comment: you answered my question perfectly, but I do have another question. Instead of redirecting to a thanks.html page, It would be nice to have a success message delivered on the current page. That is most likely more advanced using ajax, but I figure a simple javascript alert can be used. How would you implement a javascript alert saying, thank you for your message?

Comment: @JCHASE11 there is no simple way to implement ajax or javascript. But I added simple HTML tag to do automatic redirect

Comment: I asked this on another S.O. question, and credited you...This solution is a workaround, but It  still involves leaving the page, and then bringing you back, correct? I am looking for a solution that keeps you on the existing page.

Answer (score 0):

For simple and hard tasks *(it does HTML mail)* this library always served me well: [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)

Depending on servers and administrators, sometimes `mail()` doesn't work.
It must be configured to work correctly with smtp or have a sendmail binary installed in the correct path.

PHPMailer, instead, only needs outbound connection trough fsockopen not to be disabled.

A simple tutorial here:
http://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/send-mail-using-phpmailer-en/

A number of CMS uses it internally, too. Joomla, for example.

Comment: Ive heard about PHPMailer and looked at it. It seemed intimidating. I will give it a shot now.

Comment: The main site *is* intimidating, indeed, and could sport better quick starts, but once you read one from a third party, you're set.

Comment: this particular third party tut would take me hours to figure out. Again, with little to no experience in PHP, I would have to do a lot of trial and error, which Is why I am searching for a very easy, basic solution